# Angular 2.Accessing child view

Tags: angular

I use ng2-bootstrap and modal component. But, question is not about ng2-bootstrap.  I have the following template in my `root` component:

```
... for brevity
<div bsModal #lgModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" (click)="lgModal.hide()" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Header</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Modal body</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get `lgModal` in a component. So, in the component I have:

```
@ViewChild('lgModal')
public lgModal: ModalDirective;
```

All works fine. But, I want to put modal html to separate component. For example, `app-modal`. Then, in the `root` component I have:

```
...for brevity
<app-modal></app-modal>
```

But, in this case, the `lgModal` is undefined in the `root` component. How to get it in thi case properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your parent component define the child component like this:

```
@ViewChild(AppModalComponent) appModalComponent: AppModalComponent; //assuming the name of the child component is AppModalComponent
```

Move

```
@ViewChild('lgModal')
public lgModal: ModalDirective;
```

to the child component.
Then you can access the `lgModal` property that is in the child component with

```
this.appModalComponent.lgModal = "something";
```

in your parent component.

Ref: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-calls-a-viewchild-

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the answer.